# 404 error on using graph API from c# console app

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am currently trying to authenticate Graph API using my C#. I am able to query this API and receive the token successfully from Postman.But when I call same API, I get 404 error.

My code is as below:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace GraphTest
{
    public class AuthenticationModel
    {
        public string grantType { get; set; } = "client_credentials";
        public string clientId { get; set; } = "my_ad_app_id";
        public string clientSecret { get; set; } = "client_secret";
        public string scope { get; set; } = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";
    } 
    public class Authentication
    {
        private static string tenantId = "tenant_id";
        private static readonly HttpClient Client = new HttpClient();
        public Authentication()
        {
           var authenticationModel = new AuthenticationModel();
           RunAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        private static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://login.microsoftonline.com/");
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("*/*"));
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "login.microsoftonline.com");
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");

            try
            {
                var authenticationModel = new AuthenticationModel();
                var url = await GetTokenAsync(authenticationModel);
                Console.WriteLine($"Created at {url}");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }
        }

        private static async Task<Uri> GetTokenAsync(AuthenticationModel authenticationModel)
        {
            var keyValues = authenticationModel.GetType().GetProperties()
                .ToList()
                .Select(p => $"{p.Name} = {p.GetValue(authenticationModel)}")
                .ToArray();
            var xUrlEncodedBody = string.Join('&', keyValues);
            var response = await Client.PostAsJsonAsync(
                $"{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/token", xUrlEncodedBody);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

So, I recieve this in response: `StatusCode:404, ReasonPhrase:Not Found`
Please help me in knowing that where I am doing it wrong.

Note: API with same data works fine with Postman. Though, I have replaced some values here for security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not post form URL encoded content as JSON (`PostAsJsonAsync`). The body needs to have a content type of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

But backing up a second, you don't need to implement the protocol yourself when there are libraries out there that do it for you :). We provide and support the [Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL)](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet) which makes this easy.

```
var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(config.ClientId)
              .WithTenantId("{tenantID}")
              .WithClientSecret(config.ClientSecret)
              .Build();

string[] scopes = new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };

AuthenticationResult result = null;

try
{
    result = await app.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (MsalServiceException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error getting token: {ex.Message}");
}

Console.WriteLine($"Token: {result.AccessToken}");
```

Comment: I have been using this and it works, but I would like to use Postman to write tests when I don't want to write out the entire thing in C#

Answer (score -1):

I ran your code and it is wrongly generating query string as below with spaces.

```
xUrlEncodedBody => grantType = client_credentials&clientId = my_ad_app_id&clientSecret = client_secret&scope = https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

There is space between query parameter name and value, see below line.

```
.Select(p => $"{p.Name} = {p.GetValue(authenticationModel)}")
```

Remove the space and try again

```
.Select(p => $"{p.Name}={p.GetValue(authenticationModel)}")
```

Comment: Link to my postman collection is as follows:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BNJQZJOeqdjWsB4OiPIs9KnsZWWkYZEJ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I ran your code and it is wrongly generating query string like below. See the solution proposed and try once.

Comment: Problem is still same. My question is that if my body data is incorrect, it should throw a 400 error. But the problem here is that here it throws 404 i.e. the URL I am trying to hit does not exist. While the exact same URL exist when I call from Postman